# Why is mSuggestedFriends null?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing an android app which uses google cloud endpoints as a backend. The backend works and can be called by the android client.

In the FindFriendFragment I call an endpoints async task class;

```
new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, getContext());
```

which fetches the suggested friends from the datastore via the exposed endpoints api and sends them back to the client;

```
return mApi.getSuggestedFriends().execute().getItems();
```

In the on post execute I use an interface;

```
public interface OnFetchedSuggestedFriends {
    void sendSuggestedFriends(List<Profile> suggestedFriends);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Profile> profiles) {
    super.onPostExecute(profiles);
    OnFetchedSuggestedFriends callback = (OnFetchedSuggestedFriends) mContext;
    callback.sendSuggestedFriends(profiles);
}
```

which the FindFriendFragment implements to send the suggested friends back to the fragment to be used;

```
public class FindFriendFragment extends Fragment
        implements EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends.OnFetchedSuggestedFriends

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_friend, container, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null)
            mUserId = user.getToken(true).toString();

        new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, getContext());

        RecyclerView suggestedFriendRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.suggested_friends_recycler_view);
        suggestedFriendRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        suggestedFriendRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        SuggestedFriendAdapter adapter = new SuggestedFriendAdapter(mSuggestedFriends, mUserId);
        suggestedFriendRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendSuggestedFriends(List<Profile> suggestedFriends) {
        mSuggestedFriends = suggestedFriends;
    }
```

however the suggested friends field is null, even though when I test my backend with the api explorer the getSuggestedFriends method returns the suggestedFriends as expected. Is this due to the api call taking a lot of time?

**EDIT:**

Here is the async task code:

```
public static class GetSuggestedFriends extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Profile>>{

        private BirthpayApi mApi;
        private String mUserId;
        private OnFetchedSuggestedFriends mListener;

        public GetSuggestedFriends(String userId, OnFetchedSuggestedFriends listener) {
            mUserId = userId;
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public interface OnFetchedSuggestedFriends {
            void sendSuggestedFriends(List<Profile> suggestedFriends);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Profile> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (mApi == null) {
                BirthpayApi.Builder builder = new BirthpayApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                        // options for running against local devappserver
                        // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                        // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                        .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                            @Override
                            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                            }
                        });
                mApi = builder.build();
            }

            try{
                return mApi.getSuggestedFriends().execute().getItems();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Profile> profiles) {
            super.onPostExecute(profiles);
            mListener.sendSuggestedFriends(profiles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post your asynctask code

Comment: Check my updated last line and now if it is not working then we can again try :) @Tom Finet

Comment: I just forgot to add .execute(). Thanks! @Hardy

Comment: Now mSuggestedFriends is not null and has the correct value, however the recycler view is not being displayed with the data. @Hardy

Comment: This is because initially mSuggestedFriends is null and later it gets set when the recycler view has already been created with the adapter. Although I call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); nothing changes, the adapter is not updated with the new data. @Hardy

Comment: Never mind fixed it by doing this in the sendSuggestedFriends(List<Profile>) method:      mSuggestedFriends.clear();
        mSuggestedFriends.addAll(suggestedFriends);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello you are not notifying your adapter check if below code works:----**

```
 public class FindFriendFragment extends Fragment
    implements EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends.OnFetchedSuggestedFriends
 SuggestedFriendAdapter adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_friend, container, false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null)
        mUserId = user.getToken(true).toString();

    new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, getContext());

    RecyclerView suggestedFriendRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.suggested_friends_recycler_view);
    suggestedFriendRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    suggestedFriendRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

  adapter = new SuggestedFriendAdapter(mSuggestedFriends, mUserId);
    suggestedFriendRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void sendSuggestedFriends(List<Profile> suggestedFriends) {
    mSuggestedFriends = suggestedFriends;
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

- getContext()* Check here your context is implementing your interface or not!!!

Use Below line instead:-

```
new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, FindFriendFragment.this);
```

**Below new line of code fr your needed context **

```
new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, getActivity(),FindFriendFragment.this);
```

**Your asynctask paramter should be !!!**

```
EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends.OnFetchedSuggestedFriends listener;
```

and define it in your constructor like....

```
GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, getActivity(),

    EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends.OnFetchedSuggestedFriends listener_)
{
  listener=listener_}
```

**Your on post will look like this...**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Profile> profiles) {
    super.onPostExecute(profiles);
    listener.sendSuggestedFriends(profiles);
}
```

**:) Final trial line :-**

```
 new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, getActivity(),FindFriendFragment.this).execute();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, the fragment is still blank due to mSuggestedFriends == null;

Comment: Print LOG in sendSuggestedFriends method what are you getting? @TomFinet

Comment: you want me to Log.i() the suggestedFriends field? @Hardy

Comment: Wow, it does not get called. The Log statement does not get called, no wonder mSuggestedFriends is null, but why? @Hardy

Comment: @TomFinet check my last line

Comment: Ok makes sense, but does this mean that my Activity holding this fragment should implement interface and not the fragment or should I declare my activity as abstract.

Comment: Actually this causes the error: Error:(125, 24) error: incompatible types: FindFriendFragment cannot be converted to Context. The async task class requires a context not a fragment.                                                      The line:                                                new EndpointTask.GetSuggestedFriends(mUserId, FindFriendFragment.this); causes the error, apparently FindFriendFragment.this is not of type context.

Comment: @TomFinet if you want to use context then apply another param for interface check ans now

Comment: How would this help as the getActivity() returns the context for MainActivity not for the fragment. @Hardy

Comment: This still does not work, sendSuggestedFriends is still not being called as well as the Log statement inside it. @Hardy

Comment: @TomFinet you can accept answer if it helped to you thanks!